# generate PDF with multiple pages with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, puppeteer

I created a React App, and nodejs server.
I have a big problem with my puppeteer.
I want to create a PDF with multiple pages.
But when the PDF is rendering, i have only one page and not all my content.

I am using puppeteer v-4.0.0

Can anybody help me ?
thank you [image]

Comment: Can you please replace the attached screenshot with a pasted code snippet like this: \```javascript <code goes here> \```

Answer (score 2):

You have hidden code for this example, therefore I cannot tell what is happening 100%.

There are two approaches to this. You can add all the content of your web app in one page or have Puppeteer looping through a list of pages. The idea of creating multiple pages has to do with CSS paged media. In other words, if a website was already printing in multiple pages for a given document, Puppeteer follows along and will do the same thing.

In a nutshell, you know when your print is ready when you can simply do this in Chrome as a user:

Windows

**Control + P > Hit on the Print Button**

Mac

**Command + P > Hit on the Print Button**

What you saw there, is what you will be getting.

Nevertheless, if your code is indicating the headless browser to behave as screen e.g. `await page.emulateMediaType('screen');` You are going to end up with a single huge chunk of PDF in some cases, similar to what a user would have done trying to print that page using Chrome.

If you are printing things like documentations, maybe amending to the concept of a print page is not a bad idea. For instance the print page would know how to gather all documents and bundle all of it to a single format which could then be printed afterwards. This results in a single PDF file, you would then have full control of from the client-side.

But sometimes, this sort of bundling may be too cumbersome or not ideal, you then would have to loop through pages like this:

```
const pages = [
   'relative-path-1',
   'relative-path-2',
   'relative-path-3'
];

let index = 0;

for (let link of pages){
  index++;
  await page.goto('the website address' + link);
  await page.pdf({
    path: 'Page-' + index + '.pdf'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer.js =>

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
         AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3419.0 Safari/537.36');
    await page.goto('http://localhost:1234/pdf');
    await page.emulateMedia('screen');
    await page.pdf({ path: 'src/components/reportPdf.pdf'});
    await browser.close();
})()
```

Package.json =>

```
{
  "name": "copro-expert",
  "homepage": ".",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Copro Expertises",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "clean": "rm dist/bundle.js",
  "start": "parcel public/index.html",
  "build": "parcel build public/index.html --out-dir build --no-source-maps --no- 
  content-hash",
  "deploy": "npm run build && firebase deploy",
  "generate": "npx babel-node src/server/puppeteer.js"
  },
  "repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "git+https://github.com/ovieokeh/lists-pwa.git"
  },
   "keywords": [
     "firebase",
     "pwa",
     "react"
   ],
  "author": "Ovie Okeh",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ovieokeh/lists-pwa/issues"
 },
 "dependencies": {
 "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
 "@babel/node": "^7.10.3",
 "axios": "^0.19.2",
 "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
 "express": "^4.17.1",
 "faker": "^4.1.0",
 "fetch-base64": "^2.1.2",
 "firebase": "^7.15.1",
 "hookrouter": "^1.2.3",
 "moment": "^2.24.0",
 "node": "^14.4.0",
 "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
 "puppeteer": "^4.0.0",
 "react": "^16.12.0",
 "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
 "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
 "redux": "^4.0.5",
 "save": "^2.4.0",
 "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
 "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2",
 "wkhtmltopdf": "^0.3.4",
 "ws": "^7.3.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "less": "^3.10.3",
   "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3"
 }
}
```

PdfReport.jsx =>

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button, Modal } from "semantic-ui-react";

const PdfReport = () => { 
  return (
    <div className="PdfReport page">                     
        <div>a</div>         
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PdfReport;
```

Then i run the command => "npm run generate"
And I got only one page.
I tried puppeteer with another new project react, and it works.
So i don't know what's wrong in my project.

Comment: `await page.emulateMediaType`